# Omit unwanted text stretching in latex documents

Tags: latex

I have the following problem with my latex document (see the red marked area in the picture). I want to scratch the words like in the green marked area.

[image: my latex problem :) - see the red area]

I guess that this misbehavior evolves through my style settings.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,parskip=full,normalheadings,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=40mm,outer=30mm,top=33mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{times}                            % font-style
\usepackage{graphicx}                         % figures
\usepackage[square]{natbib}                   % for references
\usepackage{csquotes}                         % quotes
\usepackage{verbatim}                         % comment-environment
\linespread{1.10}                             % line distance
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.pdftex}{pdf}{.pdftex}{} % for xfig
\usepackage{tabularx}                         % tables
\usepackage{srcltx}                           % forward/reverse search in dvi
\usepackage[perpage,marginal,hang]{footmisc}  % make special footnote symbols
\sloppy                                       % prevent overfull boxes

%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                                % damit das Inhaltsverzeichnis auf deutsch ist

%% styling the header and footer
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}                    % separation line in the header
    \clearscrheadfoot
    \automark[subsection]{section}      
    \lehead[]{\leftmark}
    \lohead[]{\rightmark}
    \rehead{\pagemark}
    \rohead{\pagemark}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}


%% color
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{.5,0,0}
    \definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.5}

\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=darkblue,pagecolor=darkred,
citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}


%% settings for caption
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,textfont=it,singlelinecheck=false,format=hang]{caption}


% counter hack for setting the counter for the listings
\usepackage{chngcntr}
    \counterwithin{figure}{section}
    \counterwithin{table}{section}
```

If you can, please tell me, which option I have to change in order to get a 'fine word stretching' for the whole document.

As always, thanks for your fast and helpful answers.

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is connected with url. Url adress is printed as one word without spaces. You may add \newline before "http://...."

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for your help, but this does not solve my problem.

Comment: How do you specify literature item?